# AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.insert failed

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the below code but getting the error "API call to directory.resources.calendars.insert failed with error Entity already exist" pl help me to fix this error. Also , i want to put the error handlar   while insearting the calendar resources.  where do i put error handlar in below code

```
var cus = 'my_customer';

for (i=1; i < dataset.length; i++) {

   var res = {

     resourceName : dataset[i][0],

    resourceId : dataset[i][1],

    resourceType : dataset[i][2]
  }

}

 AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.insert(res, cus);
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of `res` and `cus`? Mind that you can edit the same resource only once.

Comment: thx  ziganotschka for reply..i hv udpated the code for res and cust values

Answer (score 0):

### Each resource needs a unique `resourceId`

The error

> Entity already exist

means that `'my_customer'` already has a resource with the same `resourceId` you try to insert.

You can verify it with `AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.list()`.

If your dataset has several entries with the same resourceId,you can avoid an error e.g. as following:

```js
  for (i=0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
    var resources = AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.list(cus).items;    
    var existingIds = []; 
    resources.forEach(function(resource){existingIds.push(resource.resourceId)});
    if(existingIds.indexOf(dataset[i][1].toString()) ==-1){    
      var res = {        
        resourceName : dataset[i][0],        
        resourceId : dataset[i][1],        
        resourceType : dataset[i][2]
      }      
      AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.insert(res, cus);  
    }else{
      Logger.log("Resource with id " +   dataset[i][0] + " exists already");
    }
  }
```

Note:

The sample above is not necessary the most elegant solution, you might consider filtering the dataset first to remove duplicates.

Comment: thx ziganotschka for reply. I have checked it ,there is no duplicate resourceId. i checked with your above code but iam still getting the same error.  Also, i did not understand what is "my_customer"  in the code.

Comment: `my_customer` is a alias that you can use as an admin to represent your account's customer ID. Can you log `existingIds` and compare them to the dataset?

Comment: Or alternatively: `resources.forEach(function(resource){Logger.log("existing id: " + resource.resourceId)});`